# How to only change the hour and seconds portion of a utc timestamp?

Tags: javascript, timestamp, utc

I've got a UTC timestamp in milliseconds. 
It represents 16:00 on a certain day in GMT time.

> timestamp:  1450281600000

I want to modify only the hours, minutes component portion of this value and return the new value.

For example `16:30` is `59400000` but it doesn't have the days and year.

How do I correctly change the utc stamp?

I'm programming in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Throw your timestamp into a Date object, manipulate it with the date functions, and then use valueOf to return a timestamp again.

```js
var d = new Date(1450281600000);
d.setHours(1);
d.setMinutes(30);
alert(d.valueOf()); // 1450247400000
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use [standard Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

For example, to change 16:00 to 16:30 of that day, you'd do like this:

```
dt = new Date(1450281600000); // instatiates Date from timestamp
// Wed Dec 16 2015 17:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) in my local representation
dt.getMinutes(); // will return 0
dt.setMinutes(30);
// dt now is represented as 1450283400000 timestamp...
dt.getTime(); // ...which you can see here.
```